# I am using iphone 6 and my battery Max capacity is 1118 mAH and design capacity is 1751?

Tags: iphone, battery, jailbreak

[image]

I am using iphone 6 ios 9.3.3 my battery Max capacity is 1118 mAH and design capacity is 1751 ?

Why its Max capacity is is not 1751 what to do to fix it.

Comment: Is this a brand-new iPhone 6 or have you been using it for 2 years?  Max capacity is reduced by charging and usage.

Comment: i bought it in December  month 2014.

Answer (score 3):

**Your battery is worn out**

Batteries, particularly lithium-ion batteries loose the ability to hold charge as they age. The biggest indicator of how old a battery is is not just the age but the charge cycle count, which is the number of time the battery is charged to 100% and discharged again back to 0. Note that this doesn't have to happen all in one charge but is cumulative.

[Apple has some good information on it here.](http://www.apple.com/batteries/why-lithium-ion/)

645 charge cycles is a lot. The current estimate of the lifespan of an iPhone battery is  [300 - 400 charge cycles](http://www.macworld.com/article/1058916/smartphones/iphonebattery.html) There is nothing you can really do to fix this except use the iPhone in such a way to maximise the remaining life of the battery. More information can be found [here.](http://www.apple.com/batteries/maximizing-performance/)